# Trigger in DB2 - Error when trying to fill an XML column

Tags: python, sql, db2

I'm trying to execute the following trigger in DB2 (simplifying it a little bit to make it tractable) using Python:

"CREATE TRIGGER GGGG AFTER INSERT ON HHHH FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL INSERT INTO Message11 (ID, Message) VALUES (88, XMLDOCUMENT(XMLELEMENT(NAME 'HELLO', 'rp')))"

I'm getting the following error message:

SQLCODE=-440ion: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "XMLELEMENT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42884

Any clues why this is happening?

Comment: What is  `'rp'` ?

Comment: Just a string. I used it as an example.

Comment: Needs to be a valid namespace. Get the XMLELEMENT working outside the trigger (e.g. use the `VALUES XMLELEMENT( NAME "HELLO", xmlnamespace(...))`  at the clp or in any gui tool), then build up the xmldocument, and get a test insert working. When you have a working insert, then retry the trigger with correct syntax.

Comment: The element name must be enclosed into double quotes, not into single ones. Use "HELLO" instead of 'HELLO'.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your comments and your willingness to help. I did the following slight modification to the code, and it worked: 'CREATE TRIGGER GGGG AFTER INSERT ON HHHH FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL INSERT INTO Message11 (ID, Message) VALUES (88, XMLDOCUMENT(XMLELEMENT(NAME "HELLO", INTEGER(10))))'  It seems it's a problem with strings.